# SQL Server: how can I insert current date into database?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

SQL Server: how can I get current date with the following format?

I have the following code to insert date to table but how can get `CURDATE()`
in the formats listed below

```
 INSERT INTO [MIBOMH] 
   ([bomItem], [bomRev], [rollup], [mult], [autoBuild], [assyLead],[revCmnt],[author],[descr],[qPerLead],[lstMainDt],[revDate],[effStartDate],[ovride] )
 SELECT DISTINCT [bomitem], [bomrev], '1', '1', '1', '3','SYNC ','AUTHORNAME','SYNC','0', '2016-07-12 14:10:19.427','20160712','20160712','0'
FROM [DB].[dbo].[whlmibomh]
  WHERE  [bomitem] IN (SELECT [ItemID] FROM [MIITEM] WHERE type='2')
 AND [bomitem] NOT IN (SELECT [bomItem] FROM [MIBOMH])
```

Desired formats:

1. '2016-07-12 14:10:19.427'
2. '20160712'
3. '20160712'

Comment: SQL Server >= 2012: [`FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: @RubensFarias yes its 2012

Comment: Aside: Is there some reason that you are choosing to store dates and times as prose rather than using a more suitable data type, e.g. [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)? It may cause your bum to be nibbled in the future when you attempt to _use_ the data. As a rule, formatting should be left up to the application(s) that interact with users, not inflicted on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with [`FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();  
SELECT  FORMAT(@d, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss\.fff', 'en-US') AS 'Format#1'  
       ,FORMAT(@d, 'yyyyMMdd'                  , 'en-US') AS 'Format#2'
```

Comment: Date/time values should be stored using propper data types : datetime,  smalldatetime,  date,  time,  datetime2,  datetimeoffset and not within [n]varchar columns/variables